# How to change name of control in server side?

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

I,ve created a dropdown in server side. my code is :

```
 Dim dd As DropDownList = New DropDownList()
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim clsCareer As New merchant
 Dim _dr_fill_dll_senf As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
 dd.Items.Add("Senf")
 dd.SelectedItem.Value = "0"
 _dr_fill_dll_senf = clsCareer.GetAllParentSenf()
 dd.SelectedItem.Value = selectedValue
 n = 1
 Do While _dr_fill_dll_senf.Read
     dd.Items().Add(_dr_fill_dll_senf.Item("description") + " (" + _dr_fill_dll_senf.Item("code") + ")")
     dd.Items(n).Value = _dr_fill_dll_senf.Item("code")
     n = n + 1
 Loop
 _dr_fill_dll_senf.Close()
 Panel1.Controls.Add(dd)
```

My problem is: I want to set name of this dropdown in server side.... but when page is load name is created automatically but i want set name custom

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? Id attribute of generated html control?

Comment: `dd.ID="youdropdownName"`?

Comment: yes but dd.Name doesnt have. i mean name of dropdown....

Comment: How do you check "name" of your control?

Comment: I just want to set name of my dropdown with my self in above code. asp automatically creat a name for any control...but i want to set name of dropdown custome....

Comment: Please read first comment - what do you mean by "name" of the control?

Comment: Can you describe your exact requirement ? so that we can provide you suggestion to achieve it in better way.

Comment: in code I can set dd.id="anything" but there is not dd.Name...it means you can not set dd.Name because asp automatically create name of dropdown but i want set name of dropdown by myself....